# Android application to show upload and download speed in the status bar only if the network traffic is above a defined threshold

Tags: android, network-monitor

I am looking for an Android application that can display your current speed in the status bar only if the network traffic is above a defined threshold. The application [Internet Speed Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter.lite) can displays the current speed in status bar but it cannot be configured it so that it only displays the information when the network traffic is more than X kbps:

[image]